# RestTemplateBuilder with custom CloseableHttpClient still throws SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

## Situation

I have to test app with connecting to test server that has self signed certificate. To achieve this I do the following:

1. I am using **RestTemplateBuilder** from Spring framework to create **RestTemplate**
2. I pass in custom configured **HttpClient** that should ignore hostname verification.

## Problem

In spite of custom http client I still get **SSLPeerUnverifiedException**. Any clues?

## Code

Part of the code responsible for configuring RestTemplate:

```
public class RestTemplateForBasicAuth {
  private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

  public RestTemplateForBasicAuth(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    this.restTemplateBuilder = restTemplateBuilder;
  }

  public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(String host) {

    // Initialize http client that does not complain on self signed certificate
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build();
    HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(host);
    final AuthHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new AuthHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient, httpHost, "user", "xxx");
    restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(requestFactory);
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    restTemplateBuilder.messageConverters(messageConverter);
    return restTemplateBuilder.build();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the proper Annotations from Spring (Boot)?

You have to annotate the class with `@Configuration` and the method `getRestTemplate(...)` with `@Bean` at least if it is a Spring Boot Application.